# Computer does not shut down with this code (C sharp)

Tags: c#, timer, shutdown, numericupdown

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int minutes = Convert.ToInt32(numericUpDown1.Value);

        if (minutes > 0)
        {
            int secs = minutes * 60;
            progressBar1.Maximum = secs;
            timer1.Enabled = true;

            stopwatch.Start();
            timer1.Start();

            if (stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes==numericUpDown1.Value)
            {
                Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
                stopwatch.Stop();
                timer1.Stop();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter the correct minutes");
            numericUpDown1.Value = 0;
        }
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        progressBar1.Increment(1);
    }
```

It seems like the the value of the numbericUpDown is not recognised.

Comment: you already created `int minutes` why aren't you comparing against that

Comment: I tried doing that but it still doesn't work.

Comment: How is that supposed to work? You start a stopwatch and check it almost immediately, nothing after that. This needs to be completely reworked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is some error in you code Suggestion:

```
 int secs = minutes * 60;
 progressBar1.Maximum = secs;
 timer1.Enabled = true;

 stopwatch.Start();
 timer1.Start();

 if (stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes==numericUpDown1.Value)
 {
     Process.Start("shutdown", "/s /t 0");
     stopwatch.Stop();
     timer1.Stop();
 }
```

What happens if you get there?
You start your stopwatch and your timer. But nothing will wait for your timer. So you check for `(stopwatch.Elapsed.Minutes==numericUpDown1.Value)` which will execute just a few milliseconds after you started your code - your program won't check for the statement ever again, till you press your `button` again and so will never shutdown, because if you click your button you set your time to the new value again.

```
bool goon = true;
while(goon)
{
    //... check your time here
    // if true goon = false;
}
```